# Concatenar listas de listas en Python

Tags: python, lista

Cómo puedo pasar de esto `list = [[uno, dos, tres],[a,b,c],[1,2,3]]` a esto `list1 = [uno, dos, tres,a,b,c,1,2,3]`

intenté con  `[ ",".join(sublista) for sublista in list]` pero no une las listas en un solo vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero: No uses `list` como nombre de variable, ya que [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) es una función integrada en el lenguaje que estás sobreescribiendo.

Si la lista está compuesta de sublistas de una sola dimensión, con comprehension es sencillo:

```py
>>> li = [['uno', 'dos', 'tres'],['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]]
>>> li2 = [y for x in li for y in x]
>>> print(li2)
['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Albert mira lo que puedes hacer es usar la funcion numpy.concatenate(), la cual se encarga de concatenar multiples arreglos segun el eje especificado que seria el segundo parametro que pasamos a la funcion siendo este axis=0,

seria algo como

```
    liArr = [['uno', 'dos', 'tres'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]
    liArr1 = np.concatenate(list, axis=0)
    print(liArr1)
    
    # El print seria ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3]
```